# Desenhando com CSS

Tags: css, css3

Existe alguma forma de desenhar uma folha como a imagem abaixo, usando o CSS ?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Eu utilizaria canvas ou melhor, svg e não ficaria sofrendo com css não rs

Comment: mas é porque eu quero aprender a fazer isso...

Comment: É extremamente complicado estilizar um elemento html do jeitinho que está a imagem, mas qual seria a utilidade de trabalhar com um elemento html estilizado ao contrário de uma imagem vetorial?

Comment: É mais pelo conhecimento mesmo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você tem que ir adaptando seu CSS para isso, olha esse exemplo default para folha:

HTML:

```
<div class="leaf"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.leaf { 
  width: 100px; height: 100px;
  background-color: #A0DE21; 
  -moz-border-radius: 100px 0px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100px 0px;
  border-radius: 100px 0px;
}
```

Veja no [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xwvyo1c5/)

Nesse [site](http://codepen.io/picks/3/#), tem vários exemplos de [animações](http://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/PGZwNq) feitas com CSS.

Tem esses outros sites também:

- [CssAnimate](http://cssanimate.com/)
- [EnjoyCSS](http://enjoycss.com/)
- [Tutorialspoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/svg_tool.htm)

Comment: http://codepen.io/katietanner/pen/PNjVeE
http://codepen.io/osublake/pen/gpGEye

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio, muito bom. Essa animação se encaixa melhor na pergunta =)

Comment: Mas ainda acho que o menos sofrível seja criar um elemento svg ou canvas rs

Comment: é menos 'sofrimento' usar um svg, mas aí é que está, eu não quero aprender a fazer as coisas possíveis, assim quem sabe um dia eu possa ajudar a todos criando bibliotecas mais completas, específicas para determinadas situações, e tantas outras coisas, sei que o SVG é mais fácil, mas de que adianta ficar só na parte fácil ?

Answer (score 6):

Pra auxiliar a montagem estou usando: http://www.cssmatic.com/box-shadow

```css
div {
  background: rgba(119, 178, 0, 1);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(119, 178, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(119, 178, 0, 1) 48%, rgba(85, 128, 0, 1) 50%, rgba(86, 128, 0, 1) 52%, rgba(120, 178, 0, 1) 55%, rgba(119, 178, 0, 1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(left top, right top, color-stop(0%, rgba(119, 178, 0, 1)), color-stop(48%, rgba(119, 178, 0, 1)), color-stop(50%, rgba(85, 128, 0, 1)), color-stop(52%, rgba(86, 128, 0, 1)), color-stop(55%, rgba(120, 178, 0, 1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(119, 178, 0, 1)));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(119, 178, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(119, 178, 0, 1) 48%, rgba(85, 128, 0, 1) 50%, rgba(86, 128, 0, 1) 52%, rgba(120, 178, 0, 1) 55%, rgba(119, 178, 0, 1) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(119, 178, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(119, 178, 0, 1) 48%, rgba(85, 128, 0, 1) 50%, rgba(86, 128, 0, 1) 52%, rgba(120, 178, 0, 1) 55%, rgba(119, 178, 0, 1) 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(119, 178, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(119, 178, 0, 1) 48%, rgba(85, 128, 0, 1) 50%, rgba(86, 128, 0, 1) 52%, rgba(120, 178, 0, 1) 55%, rgba(119, 178, 0, 1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(119, 178, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(119, 178, 0, 1) 48%, rgba(85, 128, 0, 1) 50%, rgba(86, 128, 0, 1) 52%, rgba(120, 178, 0, 1) 55%, rgba(119, 178, 0, 1) 100%);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#77b200', endColorstr='#77b200', GradientType=1);
  border-radius: 122px 122px 122px 122px;
  -moz-border-radius: 122px 122px 122px 122px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 122px 122px 122px 122px;
  border: 16px solid #ECEDEE;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 6px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.37);
  -moz-box-shadow: 6px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.37);
  box-shadow: 6px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.37);
  -ms-transform: rotate(60deg);
  /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(60deg);
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  transform: rotate(60deg);
  height:256px;
  width:200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 10%;
}

/*
div:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 100% 50%;
  border-style: groove hidden hidden hidden;
  border-color: #ff0000;
  width: 57%;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: white;
  right: 0px;
  top: 40px;
}

div:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 100% 50%;
  border-style: hidden hidden groove hidden;
  border-color: #ff0000;
  width: 50%;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: white;
  left: 0;
  top: 27px;
}
*/
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Mas veja o quão é trabalhoso, e fica longe daquilo imaginado, se tornando meio inviável.

---

Depois tento terminar de "desenhar" usando somente css.

---

Criando o mesmo elemento utilizando svg:

> 1° Salvei sua imagem em uma pasta;
>
> 2° Joguei a imagem [nessa ferramenta](https://svg-edit.github.io/svgedit/releases/svg-edit-2.8.1/svg-editor.html) {Projeto no [GitHub](https://github.com/SVG-Edit/svgedit)};
>
> 3° Configurei as propriedades para ficar do tamanho da imagem;
>
> 4° Cliquei em salvar a imagem.

Código fonte gerado:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<svg width="256" height="256" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <!-- Created with SVG-edit - http://svg-edit.googlecode.com/ -->
  <g>
    <title>Layer 1</title>
    <image xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,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"
    id="svg_1" height="256" width="256" y="-1" x="0" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 3):

vc tem q usar o SVG
segue um ex no fiddle mais tutorial

```html
<svg class="hello" width="230.3px" height="155.9px" viewBox="0 0 230.3 155.9">
    <path fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M0.5,0.2c2.2,5.8,0.7,12,0.9,18.2C2,33.2,4.9,48.5,7,63.2
        c2.2,15.4,5.8,30.3,7.4,45.7c1.3,13.2,0.4,29.8,4.7,42c-0.3-16.9-3.1-48.5,19.5-49.6c21.2-1,11.1,25.8,23.1,37.2
        c28.4,27,66.2-29,34.8-38.2c-7.2,17.2-5.8,50.6,21.5,44.5c14.1-3.2,20.7-26.4,22.9-39.2c1.3-7.5,12.1-75.8,1-73.9
        c-12.1,2.1-15.8,45.5-16.3,54.4c-0.8,14.8,1.3,26.9,6.8,40.2c4.6,11,6.9,19.4,19.3,20.7c14.3,1.6,21.8-11.7,27.2-24
        c8.4-19.3,6.5-43,6.5-64c0-7.3-4.1-27-13-15.4c-4.3,5.6-4.1,23.6-4.4,30.7c-0.5,11.9-1.1,24.4,2.4,35.7c5,15.9,14.8,31.2,30.1,38.3
        c7.9,3.7,19.4,7.5,25.9-0.5c3.6-4.4,4.6-23.3,2.2-28.6c-5.5-12.5-25-10.9-29.4,1.6c-5.2,14.8,1.6,25.3,9,34.8"/>
</svg>
```

link para tutorial explicativo

https://willianjusten.com.br/efeito-de-desenhar-com-svg/

Comment: "vc tem q usar" acho errôneo afirmar, porém é o caminho menos sofrível.

Comment: fui muito imperativo nessa afirmação , mas acredito que seja a melhor solução mesmo.

Answer (score 2):

Vc pode tentar "envergar" a `div` usando valores absurdos para cada um dos vértices com `border-radius`

A parte interna da folha vc pode fazer usando `repeating-radial-gradient` com `ellipse` e um `box-shadow inset` por cima para ajustar o sombreamento da cor.

Veja como fica:

```css
div {
    margin-left:100px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
    border-top-left-radius: 1430%;
    border-top-right-radius: 210%;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 410%;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 1260%;
    background: repeating-radial-gradient(ellipse at top left, #85C500, #85C500 95px, #5D8A00 95px, #5D8A00 100px, #85C500 100px);
    border: 8px solid #ECEDEE;
    box-shadow: -1px 0px 8px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), inset 0 30px 30px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    transform: rotate(-135deg);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```