# Dificuldade em fazer um Shape diferente

Tags: html, css, html5, aplicação-web, front-end

```css
div {
 width: 280px;
 height: 280px;
 background: #1e90ff;
 -webkit-clip-path: polygon(15% 0, 100% 0%, 100% 29%, 41% 49%);
clip-path: polygon(15% 0, 100% 0%, 100% 29%, 41% 49%);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Bom dia, boa tarde e boa noite.

Estou tentando fazer um `shape` num formato diferente só que não consegui. Tentei fazer com `border` e `polygon`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

É esse o formato! Se alguém souber de alguma forma de fazer isso ai! Eu até consegui fazer o formato com o `polygon`, mas não consegui arredondar a ponta de baixo

Comment: Tem algum gradiente ou é cor sólida? Uma alternativa poderia ser SVG.

Comment: Coloquei o código usando polygon. só não consegui arredondar a ponta.

Comment: Eu percebi kkkk até da pra fazer a ponta arredondada mas eu ia ter q colocar na mão ponto por ponto da parte redonda.

Comment: Talvez as respostas dessa pergunta, sejam úteis para você: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/159540/51124

Answer (score 0):

`Clip-path` tem o suporte limitado ainda e não funciona no IE ou Edge por exemplo https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path. Então o que eu te indicaria é usar uma sequencia de `Transforms` para ajustar perfeitamente o seu `shape`.

Eu fiz esse passo a passo aplicando individualmente cada um dos `transforms` para vc entender melhor como a forma foi construída. Deixei tudo comentado no código. Leia tb a documentação da Mozilla sobre `Transform`: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/transform

```css
.box {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-right: 10px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.shape {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
/* coloca os cantos arredondados */
    border-radius: 10px;
/* coloca o gradiente de cor de fundo */
    background-image: radial-gradient(royalblue, navy);
}
.box:nth-child(2) .shape{
/* desalinha o eixo vertical */
    transform: skew(30deg);
}
.box:nth-child(3) .shape{
/* desalinha o eixo vertical e rotaciona um pouco a forma no próprio eixo */
    transform: skew(30deg) rotate(-10deg);
}
.box:nth-child(4) .shape{
/* desalinha o eixo vertical e rotaciona um pouco a forma no próprio eixo e ajusta a posição no topo a direita usando X, Y */
    transform: skew(30deg) rotate(-10deg) translate(60%, -50%);
}
.box:nth-child(4) {
    transform: scale(2) translate(25%, 25%);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <div class="shape"></div>
</div>
<div class="box">
    <div class="shape"></div>
</div>
<div class="box">
    <div class="shape"></div>
</div>
<div class="box">
    <div class="shape"></div>
</div>
```